# ValueError: option names already added pytest

Tags: python, pytest, valueerror

```
#conftest.py

include pytest
def pytest_addoption(parser):
   parcer.addoption("--add", action="append")

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def adding(request):
    name_value = request.config.option.add
    if name_value == "plus":
        arg1 = 1
        arg2 = 2
        return arg1, arg2

#addition.py

@mark.first
def test_Valid_US_Phone_Number_1(adding):
    val1, val2 = adding
    assert val1 + val2 == 3
```

Running the command

```
$pytest -m first plusplus.py --add plus
```

I am getting the following error, can anybody help?

```
File "c:\users\g702823\appdata\local\continuum1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\argparsing.py", line 72, in addoption
self._anonymous.addoption(*opts, **attrs)

File "c:\users\g702823\appdata\local\continuum1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\argparsing.py", line 303, in addoption
raise ValueError("option names %s already added" % conflict)

ValueError: option names {'--add'} already added
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue myself, it turned out that I had another `conftest.py` file copied to a directory one level higher in hierarchy, so pytest actually "saw" (and was trying to load) both of them, and he detected option with name "--add" twice.

Comment: I experienced the same, but it was actually in my home directory.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @kjelderg I guess pytest actually scans the whole directory tree bottom-up, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue by deleting a `.pytest_cache` directory in the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent `pytest` from walking into directories it shouldn't (`out` and `build` in my case) by adding this to `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
norecursedirs=out build
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a conflict with a different testrail package, that I had previously installed with pip.

I listed the testrail pip packages on my system with:

`pip freeze | grep testrail`

and then uninstalled the old testrail package I had with:

`pip uninstall <testrail-package-name>`

This solved the issue.